# Chai request not working from one nginx server to another

Tags: node.js, nginx, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing node js application.

In my application I have mocha tests where I'm writing E2E tests writing chai requests. 
Everything works well expect one thing. Calling external HTTP resource but only in one case.

What is happening?

When I run my tests locally everything works well and I'm getting response from `http://example.com/example/path` which is called by following chai request

```
chai.request("http://example.com")
                .post("/example/path")
                .set("content-type", "application/json")
                .set("Connection", "keep-alive")
                .send({
                    email: "example@email.com",
                    password: "examplepassword",
                })
                .end(function(err: Error, res: IResponse): void {
                    const response: IBodyResponse = res.body;
                    resolve(response.jwt);
                });
```

But when I deploy my application using Strider ( CI/CD tool ) tests are run on that server. So when it comes to above test ( chai request ) it stuck and get into timeout after 1 or 2 minutes.

I don't know where to look because it is weird issue. Works when I run tests locally but not when they are running on a deployed server.

That sounds for me like some issue in nginx configuration?

Then I tried to make `curl` POST request from `SERVER A` to server `example.com/example/path` and it works.

Any advice  what can be wrong is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't sound like an Nginx config problem to me. Sounds much more like some sort of crazy colons in your final promise problem, and then learning the hard way why it's important to use rejection handlers when working with promises to me...

Comment: I add rejection now, but rejection happens on timeout there is no any other error. Sounds like I never received response from the server when I'm in mocha and on server.

Comment: is the domain using https on server?